# Will Linux Mint 18 support Snap Packages?

Tags: linux-mint

[Snap Packages](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-lts-snap-packages) are a new way of installing apps in Ubuntu 16.04. Its purpose is to allow LTS systems to have the latest versions of apps.

Will this be supported in Linux Mint 18?

**Update:** Now Linux Mint 18 is out. Can someone answer this question?

Comment: This sounds a bit like predicting the future; wouldn't a Mint forum have a better chance of an authoritative answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Linux Mint is community driven and future features are in the public domain. Probably someone knows where to look. A Mint forum is an option, but Linux Mint questions are on-topic here too.

Comment: Small quote in [this article](http://www.neowin.net/news/ubuntu-1604-lts-will-bring-snap-packages-for-up-to-date-apps): `(...) Derivatives of Ubuntu such as Linux Mint will be able to run snap-packaged software too.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no, and maybe. 
Initially no, but its due in 18.1 according to [Here](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3068) and [Here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-mint-18-1-to-come-with-cinnamon-3-2-mate-1-16-flatpak-and-snap-support-505852.shtml). 
Although according to a better source, namely the [mint roadmap](https://github.com/linuxmint/Roadmap), it is being "considered" for 18.2.

The only way to know is to wait and find out. (or go ask Clem directly)